# Django dockerfile can't open file '/app/src/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: docker

I have a default Django project that I want to Dockerize. I also want to set up a volume to move the src directory.
When I create the container I get an error: `python: can't open file '/app/src/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir ./src
COPY ./src ./src
VOLUME /app/src
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "src/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

#### Error

```
$ docker build -t django-img .
$ docker run -v ./src:/app/src -p 8000:8000 django-img
python: can't open file '/app/src/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

#### Project Tree structure

```
- .venv
- requirement.txt
- dockerfile
- src
-- component1
--- ...
-- src
--- .env
--- settings.py
--- urls.py
-- manage.py
```

Comment: Do you actually have `src/manage.py`, or is the script at the top level?  (Do you actually have a `src/src/` directory?)  The `docker run -v` option means you're not actually running the code in the image; does deleting this option and the unnecessary Dockerfile `VOLUME` statement make a difference?

Comment: Hello, @DavidMaze  I did as **jwp54** suggested. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is wrong in `CMD ["python", "src/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`

"src/manage.py" should be "/app/src/manage.py"

`WORKDIR /app` creates that directory in your new image and changes you into that new directory.  So, when you copy src over, you are copying it into /app.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

Comment: Hello, i add `CMD [... app/src/manage.py" ...]` and i do `docker run -v /src:/app/ ...`. It's work perfectly.

Comment: The original `src/manage.py` relative path will be interpreted relative to the current `WORKDIR`, so I'm not convinced making it an absolute path will make a difference.  Changing the `docker run -v` option overwrites the image's code with a different part of the host filesystem and that seems more likely to cause the setup to work.  (I'd recommend deleting that `docker run -v` option entirely, though.)